# Loopback 3 get relation from embedded model

Tags: mongodb, loopback

I'm using loopback 3 to build a backend with mongoDB.
So i have 3 models: Object, Attachment and AwsS3.

- Object has a relation Embeds2Many to Attachment.
- Attachment has a relation Many2One to AwsS3.

Objects look like that in mongoDB

```
[
    {
        "fieldA": "valueA1",
        "attachments": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "awsS3Id": "1234"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "awsS3Id": "1235"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "fieldA": "valueA2",
        "attachments": [
            {
                "id": 4,
                "awsS3Id": "1236"
            },
            {
                "id": 5,
                "awsS3Id": "1237"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

AwsS3 looks like that in mongoDB

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "url": "abc.com/1"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "url": "abc.com/2"
    }
]
```

**The question is: how can i get Objects included Attachment and AwsS3.url over the RestAPI?**

I have try with the `include` and `scope` filter. But it didn't work. It look like, that this function is not implemented in loopback3, right? Here is what i tried over the GET request:

```
{
    "filter": {
        "include": {
            "relation": "Attachment",
            "scope": {
                "include": {
                    "relation": "awsS3",
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With this request i only got the Objects with Attachments without anything from AwsS3.

---

**UPDATE for the relation definitons**

The relation from `Object` to `Attachment`:

```
"Attachment": {
  "type": "embedsMany",
  "model": "Attachment",
  "property": "attachments",
  "options": {
    "validate": true,
    "forceId": false
  }
},
```

The relation from `Attachment` to AwsS3

in attachment.json

```
  "relations": {
    "awsS3": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "AwsS3",
      "foreignKey": ""
    }
  }
```

in AwsS3.json

```
  "relations": {
    "attachments": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "Attachment",
      "foreignKey": ""
    }
  }
```

Comment: Can you please show us how did you implement the relations in the model.json files?

Comment: @roland_katona: i have updated the relations definiton from the json files.

Answer (score 0):

Try this filter:

```
{ "filter": { "include": ["awsS3", "attachments"]}}}}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. I tried it and got the error message "relation awsS3 isnot defined for Object Modell". 
What i want i get is: `Object` --include--> `Attachment` --include--> `AwsS3`